# How do we go about versioning and/or backing up Configurations for the Amazon AWS Cloud Services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-config

Sorry, I’m sort of a newbie when it comes to Amazon AWS Cloud so sorry if I sound naïve.

For .NET developers, I’ve used Visual Studio 2019’s AWS Lambda project to code Lambda functions and ultimately deploy it to Amazon AWS cloud

However, my concern is that there is No way to version and/or back up the Configurations for the AWS Services ( i.e., S3 bucket, Amazon SNS & SQS, etc.) that are invoked and/or trigger the various AWS Lambda Functions

The problem is that IT developers who configure said AWS Services have to use the ADFS AWS Services console website’s GUI to configure the various AWS Services, and if someone mistakenly deletes an AWS Services then they lose the configuration settings as well?

How do we go about versioning and/or backing up Configurations for the AWS Services?

Answer (score 1):

There are Infrastructure as a Code frameworks like [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) and [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) designed to address that.

Comment: Thanks. What about Visual Studio 2019's AWS Serverless Application project. The AWS Serverless Application project is an alternative to AWS Lambda project. I thought the AWS Serverless Application project's serverless.template file could hold a lot of the configuration settings in question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really delete an AWS service.

it seems like you guys are kind of "new" to AWS so I will recommend using CloudFormation templates as Infrastructure As Code tool. All the configuration of how your AWS resources are supposed to look like can be added to the template and you deploy the template to create your AWS resources. Its AWS-Native and does not cost you anything.

On top of it, you also want to add your CloudFormation templates to version control system.

Comment: Thanks. Are CloudFormation templates related to Visual Studio 2019's AWS Serverless Application project's serverless.template file?

Comment: kind of. the templates you are talking about are called SAM templates. more or less same as CloudFormation templates.